# Is there a specific name for this kind of illustration style? And how can I achieve this in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, illustration

[image]

Hi everyone,

I am working on an illustration project and came across this style of illustration. It has the effect of Airbrush/Noise on the edges. I have no idea if this kind of style has a specific name to it. Also, is there a way that I can achieve the same style in my illustration(brushes, etc.)

Thanks in advance
Mayank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all styles have a name, so I can't really help you in that sense.

But you can get that grainy type of transition by setting a layer to dissolve mode. For example, make a character and shade it with a 50% hardness brush (any hardness will work) then change the mode to dissolve (drop down next to the layer opacity)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @pabombs ! The answer helped. I also found a way to achieve the same result through applying a mask and using the brush mode(using a special brush) to erase it off. This kind of gave me more control over the shape of the grains.But thanks anyways! :)